# Smooth Grid Item Transitions on Hover

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-grid, css-animation-direction

I have this table which is by default 3 columns 2 rows (3x2). When the on :hover happens it becomes 2 columns 3 rows (2x3)

default---(3x2):

|   Pig    |   Pidgeon  |   Turtle |

|   Fish   |   Cat      |   Dog    |

on hover (2x3):

|   Pig    |   Pidgeon  |

|   Turtle |   Fish     |

|   Cat    |   Dog      |

What I want to achieve:

So when the on hover happens. I want the cell to move (animation) to its destination, with a sort-of fly move to it's cel and go back the same way when I remove my cursor from there.

For example, I want to see turtle (col 3 cel 1) to move to (col 1 cel 2). But right now it's just statically becomes 3x2 or 2x3 or with my other attempts it moves outside the table. I just want A smooth transition or ease in/out of the grid positions.

```css
.main {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.root {
    display: grid;
    border: solid 1px black;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

}

.root:hover {
    display: grid;
    border: solid 1px black;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.col {
    column-span: 1;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}


.root:hover .col:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translate(50%, 0);
}

.root:hover .col:nth-child(2) {
    transform: translate(100%, 0); 
}

.root:hover .col:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
}

.root:hover .col:nth-child(4) {
    transform: translate(50%, 100%); 
}

.root:hover .col:nth-child(5) {
    transform: translate(100%, 100%); 
}

.root:hover .col:nth-child(6) {
    transform: translate(0, 200%);
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
        <div class="root">

            <div class="col">
                <label>
                   pig
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <label>
                  pidgeon
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <label>
                    turtle
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <label>
                    fish
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <label>
                    cat
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <label>
                    dog
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Most of CSS grid properties are animatable only discretely (by changing positions immediately, without smooth transitions). I'm guessing you'd have to figure out an alternative layout, or move the items with transforms or some similar method, and then apply the grid change with the delay it took to move the children. https://www.quackit.com/css/css3/animations/animatable_properties/

Comment: Since a `transform` is purely *visual* and does not actually change the layout, trying to change the grid structure with a transition is not really possible. The child transforms are relatively simple though. The first two don't change at all and the rest only change slightly by 100% in specific directions - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xxegeOy

Comment: @Y-A-U-grey FYI for future questions, You can leave out things like "need help" etc from your question's title. (See my edit suggestion and this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). StackOverflow works a bit different from forums, you can just jump straight in to where your problem is.

Comment: alright will do that thankyou  @A-Tech

Comment: @Paulie_D thankyou! css is not really my thing being stuck at such a basic thing is hurting my ego. But thanks again!

Comment: @prkos Thankyou for the link I'll look into it didn't know how to search for this on google. used this site as last resort but thank you!